# Set state false to checked radio buttons in map Component

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

```
function EachData({ data, index, open }) {
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(open);

  const toggle = (e) => {
    setisOpen((prev) => !prev);      
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      {/*<td></td>'s ... */}
      <td>
        <div className="functions">
          {!isOpen ? (
            <>
              <label className="far fa-edit" htmlFor={`label-${index + 1}`}>
                <input type="radio" name="edit" id={`label-${index + 1}`} onChange={toggle} />
              </label>
              <label className="far fa-trash"></label>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <label className="far fa-circle-check"></label>
              <label className="far fa-times-circle" htmlFor={`label-${index + 1}`} >
                <input type="radio" name="edit" id={`label-${index + 1}`} onChange={toggle} />
              </label>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default EachData;
```

App.js

```
array.map((data, index)=>{
  return(
    <EachData data={data} index={index} isOpen={false}/>
  )
})
```

When I check the radio buttons the jsx changes as expected, but after checking another radio button the previous one's state remains true. How do I set those elements state to false ?

Answer (score 1):

You should store `isOpen` state in your `array` data, not in `EachData` component

```
const [array, setArray] = useState();

const toggle = idx => {
    const newArray = array.map((item, index) => {
        if (idx == index) return {
           ...item,
           isOpen: !item.isOpen
        }
        return item
    })
    setArray(newArray);
}

array.map((data, index) => {
    return <EachData data={data} index={index} isOpen={data.isOpen} toggle={toggle} />;
});

function EachData({ data, index, isOpen, toggle }) {
    return (
        <tr>
            {/*<td></td>'s ... */}
            <td>
                <div className="functions">
                    {!isOpen ? (
                        <>
                            <label className="far fa-edit" htmlFor={`label-${index + 1}`}>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="edit"
                                    id={`label-${index + 1}`}
                                    onChange={() => toggle(index)}
                                />
                            </label>
                            <label className="far fa-trash"></label>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <label className="far fa-circle-check"></label>
                            <label className="far fa-times-circle" htmlFor={`label-${index + 1}`}>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="edit"
                                    id={`label-${index + 1}`}
                                    onChange={() => toggle(index)}
                                />
                            </label>
                        </>
                    )}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Comment: Pretty obvious `setArray(newArray)` throws infinite renders :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useRef` instead of id, here I make some logic with `useRef` I hope this would be helpful.

As per my understand, when you click on radio button in `map` function this will be activated and when you click another radio button previous radio button is still showing active, In this code I create two `useRef` as you see the below code, one is taking for all `indexes` and second for removing previous radio button active. I hope you understand this code, if you know DOM.

```
function EachData({ data, index, open }) {
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(open);

  const radioRef = useRef([]);
  const previousRadioRef = useRef([]);

  const toggle = (i) => {
    setisOpen((prev) => !prev);
    if (previousRadioRef.current && previousRadioRef.current[0] !== radioRef.current[i]) {
      if (radioRef.current[i]) {
        if (previousRadioRef.current.length) {
        previousRadioRef.current[0].checked = false;
        previousRadioRef.current = [];
      }
      radioRef.current[i].checked = true;
      previousRadioRef.current.push(radioRef.current[i]);
    }
    } else if(previousRadioRef.current && previousRadioRef.current[0]) {
       previousRadioRef.current[0].checked = false;
       previousRadioRef.current = [];
   }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <tr>
      <td>
        <div className="functions">
          {!isOpen ? (
            <>
              <label className="far fa-edit">
                <input type="radio" name="edit" ref={ref => (radioRef.current[index] = ref)} onChange={() => toggle(index)} />
              </label>
              <label className="far fa-trash"></label>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <label className="far fa-circle-check"></label>
              <label className="far fa-times-circle">
                <input type="radio" name="edit" ref={ref => (radioRef.current[index] = ref)} onChange={() => toggle(index)} />
              </label>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </>
  );
}

export default EachData;


array.map((data, index)=>{
  return(
    <EachData data={data} index={index} open={false}/>
  )
})
```

Comment: This doesn't help, btw `cardIndexRef` ??

Comment: ohh my bad, I have updated the answer, would you please try again?

Comment: I'not sure it worked, I got myself into a little mess.

Comment: It'll be good to keep the code as `<EachData data={data} index={index} isOpen={false}/>` as it got from object keys array so can't just pass it simply

Comment: yeah, I have updated the answer, you can do like this. :)

Comment: yeah but I already tried the `toggle` function and unfortunately that didn't worked

Comment: Ain't there another option for doing the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set state with the name of radio input.
Reference: http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/